# Trying to retrieve information from table and compile in top 10 List

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp, servlets

Hi i have a movie website which i coded using JSP/Servlets (MVC Architecture)

During the process when user purchase the movie, information such as movieID and Quantity of tickets purchased goes into the database.

I want to get the TOP 10 Movies tickets purchased

This is my table:

[image]

How can i (in Servlet) get the (movieID * qty) = Total number of tickets for a certain movieID

e.g. for a certain movieID (like 71)

I do not know where to start coding this logic. Please just advise me on how i should go about doing it.

Comment: something like `select MovieID, sum(qty) from table group by MovieID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.movieID, sum(t.qty) as totalQuantity from transaction t
group by t.movieId
order by sum(t.qty) desc
limit 10
```

should do the trick.

Comment: ohh thank you very much i was expecting a long process, thanks alot!